# how does java interpret a number like 000?

Tags: java, integer

in java if a program sees a number like 000 does java interpret it as 0 or does it interpret it as 000? I notice that my calculator wont even let me input 000 so it leads me to wonder if java calculates numbers in this way as well

Comment: If you were to draw 000 on a number line, how would that be any different from 0000 or 0? Since there is no difference, there is no reason for Java to pretend there is, thus it will save it as 0.

Comment: There's no such thing as "a number like 000"; it's not a valid number (that's why your calculator won't allow it). `0` is a valid number. If you're using "000", it's a string, and if you convert it to a number it becomes `0'.

Comment: Well, Java doesn't have vision, so it doesn't see anything.  The NUMBER `0` can be expressed as `0` or `00` or `00000000000` -- all valid representations of the exact same value.  The CHARACTER STRING `"0"`, however, is different from the CHARACTER STRING `"00"` or `"0000000"`.

Comment: @KenWhite -- `000` is a perfectly valid number.

Comment: thanks for the help guys, just a question thats been burning on my mind for a while with the program that im writing, wanted to cover all of my bases.

Comment: @HotLicks: OK. Show me a link that says so, and read Kristian's comment and post a number line showing where it fits. `000` is not a number - it's a string containing 3 zeros.

Comment: You could probably try it and see what happens, in less time than it took you to type the question.

Comment: @KenWhite -- 000 is the same number as 0 -- if one is a valid number the other is.  Standard rules for radix notation: 0 x 100 + 0 x 10 + 0 = 0.  And Kristian's comment in no way implies that 000 isn't a valid number.

Comment: +1: I don't understand why this question got such a bad reception. After all it's legal in Java to use such a number so I consider it a very reasonable question to ask whether there is something special about it and nobody has yet tried to explain why it is legal in Java at all.

Comment: @HotLicks, 000 is not the same number, as it isn't a number at all. Zero is zero. If you convert the string '000' into a number, it doesn't become `000`; it becomes `0`. If you have `1`, and subtract `1`, it doesn't result in `000`; it results in `0`. :) But I guess we're down to arguing silly semantics at this point, so I'll just agree that we disagree.

Comment: @KenWhite - If you convert zero to a printable with `%04d` then it prints as `0000`.  Are you saying that the C print formatter is wrong??

Comment: @HotLicks, no. I'm saying it's being "converted to a printable", which means it's been **converted**. It's no longer a number. If I print the letter 'A' four times, does that make it a new letter? No - it makes it 4 'A's in succession. Zero is '0' (as an integer), and 0.0 as a floating point number. Extending the representation doesn't change that fact. '0.0000' is no more zero than '0.0'. But like I said, I guess I'll just agree we disagree over semantics and leave this topic alone.

Comment: @KenWhite -- Ask your old high school algebra teacher what the difference is between `0` and `000`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question shows (to me) that you have a fundamental misconception about the way that Java works, and possibly a fundamental misconception about integers in the mathematical sense.

Lets start with this excerpt:

> *"... does java interpret it as 0 or does it interpret it as 000"*

This implies to me that you think there is a difference between "0" and "000" in a mathematical sense.  Plainly, there is no such difference.  Both are textual representations of the Integer zero.  The first form is the *conventional* representation, and the second one is an unconventional representation.

In short, the excerpt quoted above has no meaning in a mathematical sense.

---

Now in Java, the `int` type is most widely used representation type for mathematical integers.  And the `int` type has one and only one representation for zero.

In short, the excerpt quoted above has no meaning if we are talking about Java `int` values in the computational / behavioral sense.

---

In Java source code, integer *literals* are written as a sequence of decimal digit characters; e.g. `0`, `1`, `42` and so on.  In this context (and this context only!), an integer literal that starts with a zero is parsed as an octal number; i.e. base 8.  So in Java source `012` actually means the number ten.  However `000` interpreted as an octal number is *still* zero.

In short, the excerpt quoted above has no meaning if we are talking about literals in Java source code.

---

Finally, we need to deal with the situation where a Java application has to turn a sequence of digits entered by a user into a Java `int` value.  In this context, the conversion is typically done by calling `Integer.parseInt(...)` or something similar.  There are two distinct versions of this method:

- `Integer.parseInt(string)` expects the string to be a sequence of decimal digits (with an optional sign).  This will return the `int` zero value for both `"0"` and `"000"`.  Any leading `0` characters are simply ignored.
- `Integer.parseInt(string, radix)` expects the string to be a sequence of digits (with an optional sign) whose base is given by the `radix` argument.  Once again, leading zeros are ignored.

In short, the leading zeros are ignored, and therefore `"0"` and `"000"` will be parsed as the `int` zero, and the distinction in the quoted excerpt does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

If you enter this in a field and parse it, it is interpreted as 0. If you enter it as a literal in your code, it is an octal 0. Using octals in the code is not a great idea since it is extremely simple to confuse them.

Answer (score 3):

In Java any literal integer that starts with a 0 is interpreted as octal. So this is octal 0 which is of course dec 0.

Answer (score 2):

Java  will interpret as 0 though it is a octal evaluation.
Try out

```
int x=000; //result will be 0
```

and then

```
int x=012; // result will be 10
```